# aldeed:Autoform afFieldValueIs Helper for Array Field

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

I am trying to make autoform like this. 
What I want is Fields.$.min field to be seen only if fields.$.type ="Number". In the demo ( of aldeed:autoform) it is done for normal field but not for Array field. Tried several combinations to use afArrayField etc but no luck. Can this be done ?

```js
Registers.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
  config: {
    type: Object
  },
  'config.name': {
    type: String,
    label: 'Register Name',
    autoform: {
      'label-type': 'floating',
      placeholder: 'Register Name',


    max: 200
  }},
  **fields: {
    type: [Object]
  }**,
  'fields.$.name': {
    type: String,
    autoform: {
      'label-type': 'placeholder',
      placeholder: 'Field Name'
    }
  },
'fields.$.**min**': {
    type: String,
    autoform: {
      'label-type': 'placeholder',
      placeholder: 'Min Value'
    }
  },
  'fields.$.type': {
    type: String,
    label: 'Label',
    autoform: {
      options: [
        {value: 'String', label: 'String'},
        {value: 'Number', label: 'Number'},
        {value: 'Date', label: 'Date'},
        {value: 'Password', label: 'Password'}
      ]
    }
  }
}));
```